# Compile-time override of given base class methods

Tags: c++, templates, overriding, compile-time

Is it possible to conditionally override base methods in derived template class for parameterized base type?
I mean, I have different base classes that contain their default method definitions and I would like to define at compile time, which base class I want to use and which methods in that class I want to override, passing something like lambda function, that would be called in overridden implementation. Like:

```
struct BaseOne
{
    virtual void f(int& x, const int& y)
    {
        x += y;
    }
};

struct BaseTwo
{
    virtual void g(double& x)
    {
        x += 1.0;
    }
};

template<class BaseT/*, method m signature and ID, CallbackT callback*/>
struct Derived: public BaseT
{
    /* <mID>(mSignature)> = override
    {
        callback(<mSignatureArgs...>);
    }
    */
    // Such that here I do not have to define all methods from BaseT, that could potentially be requested to be overridden at compile-time
};

int main()
{
    Derived<BaseOne> d1; // default BaseOne::f definition
    Derived<BaseTwo, /* method g, [](double& x) { x += 2; } */> d2; // overridden BaseTwo::g definition
}
```

**Edit:** 
`BaseOne` and `BaseTwo` interfaces are generated by external tool and their interfaces cannot be changed, i.e. their interface methods are polymorphic, cannot depend on particular implementation in derived class, must have the same common base class type (no templates in base classes) and all derivatives of `BaseOne` are used like with regular polymorphism:

```
void doSomethingWithOnes(BaseOne& one)
{
    int x = /* get some x */;
    int y = /* get some y */;
    one.g(x, y); // this call must be virtual
    /* use x and y somehow */
}
```

Comment: Perhaps use `std::enable_if_v` or similar to select between two different `Derived` classes, each inheriting from the two different base classes?

Comment: Phew good question, do you know the CRTP?

Comment: @Superlokkus , interesting, have not heard before, but have just read about it. AFAIU, the CRTP is not applicable here, because in CRTP the base classes are different, e.g. if I have `template<class DerivedT> struct BaseOne` template and two different instantiations `BaseOne<Derived1>` and `BaseOne<Derived2>`, then those two instantiations would be of different class type w/o common base class. But in my case `Base*` classes must remain virtual interfaces. Actually, I cannot change base classes, because they are generated by external tool.

Comment: So do I understand you right: You must not change the Base Classes? And what do you want to achieve with those Derived classes, how do you want to use them? Please add that to you question.

Comment: Is it possible to rename `BaseTwo::g` to  `f`?

Comment: @ Superlokkus "Is it possible to rename BaseTwo::g to f?" No, it is not. Have edited the original question, hope it is clear now.

Comment: Can't you write two derived classes?

Comment: @L.F. Yes, seems it's the only way

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier to implement these as local classes:

```
int main()
{
    class : BaseOne
    {
        // default BaseOne::f definition
    } d1;

    class : BaseTwo
    {
        // overridden BaseTwo::g definition
        void g(double& x) override
        {
            x += 2;
        }
    } d2;
}
```

These can use exactly the same things a lambda could have used, and are much clearer, whilst still defined close to where they are used.

Comment: Elegant, completely forgot the existence of local classes